# Sending data from backend to Ember.JS

Tags: ember.js

anybody knows is it possible (and how to achieve that) to send some data from backend to Ember.JS, but communication should be initialized by backend?

Comment: Using sockets perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sockets to send data from backend to ember application.

https://github.com/Wildhoney/EmberSockets is a pretty good ember addon which connect to your backend through sockets.

Answer (score 0):

We are using `MessageBus` library to communicate between our Rails server and our Ember frontend. It's awesome as it is very optimized and the communication is wrapped into mechanisms that you don't want to develop yourself.

https://github.com/discourse/message_bus